# change Wireshark file (pcap file) via bittwiste (change ip)

Tags: wireshark

i want to take pcap file and change all packet with specific ip to new ip and i know i can do it in this way:

```
bittwiste.exe -I myFile.pcap -O newFile.pcap -T ip -s 192.0.16.50,61.68.133.207

bittwiste.exe -I newFile.pcap -O final.pcap -T ip -d 192.0.16.50,61.68.133.207
```

but the problem in this way is the i need to change the destination and the source ip in 2 steps and only after i can save the final file.
is it possible to do it in one step ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works for me:

```
bittwiste.exe -I newFile.pcap -O final.pcap -T ip -s 192.0.16.50,61.68.133.207 -d 192.0.16.50,61.68.133.207
```